# Simple python RFID (RC522) authentication system not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, rfid

I am a realative RPi noob so forgive me if this is a simple problem.

I am making a keycard system with the RC522 reader, and I have everything wired up correctly. It works with writing and reading cards. But for some reason when I try to compare the data, it always returns false

EX: Card is written with text "Keycard"

```
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
while True:
try:
    id, text = reader.read()
except:
    pass
print(text)
if text == "Keycard":
    print("opening")
else:
    print("Unauthorized card")
```

Now, it outputs

```
Keycard
Unauthorized card
```

Why does it not recognize text = keycard?

Comment: Perhaps there are some spaces, i.e. "Keycard  "

Comment: Thank you so much!! changed 'print(text)' to 'print(text + ",")' and it outputted '"Keycard                                   ,"'                                                                                Now i just have to count all of the spaces...

Comment: print the length of the variable `text`

Answer (score 3):

As joan pointed out in the comments above, there were extra spaces after "Keycard"